# Async expressions C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to generate a repository with some methods and including Async versions for those ones, like this:

```
    //Method 1
    public static List<MyEntity> GetMyEntityByDate(MyContextType context)
    {
        var tmpMov = context.MyEntity
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();

        return tmpMov; 

    }

    //Method 2 V1
    public async static List<MyEntity> GetMyEntityByDateAsync(MyContextType context)
    {
        var tmpMov = await context.MyEntity
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();

        return tmpMov; 
    }

    //Method 2 V2
    public async static List<MyEntity> GetMyEntityByDateAsync(MyContextType context)
    {
        List<MyEntity> tmpMov = null;  
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
            tmpMov = GetMyEntityByDate(context);
        });

        return tmpMov; 
    }
```

Now I have some questions:

What are the pros and cons of using Method 2 V1 vs Method2 V2, in terms of performance and fluency?

Before someone downvote this question, **YES** I'm implementing a repository pattern and want to write less code, thats why I'm considering V2, that way I have only one query to maintain.

But I have poor experience on **async** and obiously my target is get The best possible performance.

Comment: V1 will leverage async IO when making database query (because of ToListAsync), while V2 will not and so will not actually use any benefits of async (plus would block thread pool thread while waiting for response, for nothing). So in short, forget about V2 and use V1.

Comment: First is a `sync` way, in 2nd you only convert to list asynchronously which doesn't give any significant gain, and in 2v2 it's called async over sync, it's better to use `Task.FromResult()` than `Task.Factory.StartNew()`

Comment: `The best possible performance` <= define performance? If this is for a web server and you want to maximize the number of threads that can handle requests then v2 (with `ToListAsync`) is the best match. If you are referring to overhead in general (for a web forms or console app) then v1 is probably a better match. V3 should really not be considered at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the pros and cons of using Method 2 V1 vs Method2 V2, in terms of performance and fluency?

Method 2 V1 is a proper asynchronous method. Method 2 V2 is a fake-asynchronous method that executes blocking work on `TaskScheduler.Current` (which would be the thread pool if there is no current task scheduler).

As such, V2 runs afoul of the best practice [not to expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/).

> Before someone downvote this question, YES I'm implementing a repository pattern and want to write less code, thats why I'm considering V2, that way I have only one query to maintain.

I'd say that the ideal scenario is to actually only expose Method 2 V1, and get rid of Method 1 completely. Querying a database is inherently I/O-based, so the API is naturally asynchronous.

If you **really need** both synchronous and asynchronous APIs, then I recommend using the ["bool argument hack" as described in my MSDN article on Brownfield Async Development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

This could look like:

```
private async static Task<List<MyEntity>> DoGetMyEntityByDateAsync(MyContextType context, bool sync)
{
  var query = context.MyEntity
      .AsNoTracking();
  return sync ?
      query.ToList() :
      await query.ToListAsync();
}

public static Task<List<MyEntity>> GetMyEntityByDateAsync(MyContextType context)
{
  return DoGetMyEntityByDateAsync(context, sync: false);
}

public static List<MyEntity> GetMyEntityByDate(MyContextType context)
{
  return DoGetMyEntityByDateAsync(context, sync: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `context.MyEntity.ToList()` keeps the current thread busy until the Database finishes the query execution.

Using `await context.MyEntity.ToListAsync();` frees the current thread until the Database finishes the query execution.

Using `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { });` frees the current thread, but creates a new thread, and keeps it busy until the DB finishes the execution.

Comment: And for you what are the best way to do it  ?

Comment: `//Method 2 V1` would be the best choice from my opinion. I am also implementing this pattern in my applications as well

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez - I would advise you to also add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` after `ToListAsync` (or any other part that is async in a library call). This adds efficiency to the call and instructs the call back that it does not have to rejoin on the thread from which the call originated from. So in a library context like this it is a good thing to add. Do not use it where thread context is required like in the action method of a Mvc or Web api controller.

Comment: If possible, its good to use `async / await` whenever the process is executed by an external service (like a DB query, REST service, Disk IO etc). Similar like a waiter in a restaurant: It can take order and wait at your table until its prepared (sync way), or it can take your order, and while its prepared, it goes and takes orders from other customers as well (async way)

Comment: You forgot to mention that running synchronous method in a separate Task is an anti-pattern called `async over sync` and is not a recommended way. If some class or library provides asynchronous way to run operations - it's better to use it as it can be asynchronous on lower level.